# Start drag outside draggable div using jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I've using the first example by this code: http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#handle like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#draggable").draggable({
    handle: "p"
  });
});
```

```css
 #draggable {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   padding: 0.5em;
   float: left;
   margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
 }
 #draggable p {
   cursor: move;
 }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p class="ui-widget-header">I can be dragged only by this handle</p>
</div>
```

I would to start touch outside "draggable handle" and activate it when mouse passing over it.

I try to explain better with an image:

[image]

Is it possibile? How can I do this?